# R function to input character vector

Tags: r, function

I currently have 10 vectors that look like the following:

```
string1 <- c("house", "home", "cabin")
string2 <-c("hotel", "hostel", "motel")
```

and so on for 10 strings.

R newbie learning functions. I have the following code I want to execute across these 10 strings, and turn in to a function. This code takes in these strings and searches for matches and creates a new variable:

```
a$string.i <- (1:nrow(a) %in% c(sapply(string1, grep, a$Contents, fixed = TRUE))) +0
```

As I am new to R, I'm stumped on how to turn this into a function. Do I need to first define the number of strings, then set 'string1' in the above code to x? How do I set the name of the variable = to the name of the string?

Some sample data:

```
a <- read.table(text='Contents     other
1     "a house a home"     "111"
2     "cabin in the woods"     "121"', header=TRUE)
```

Comment: Try `nm1 <- ls(pattern="^string\\d"); lapply(mget(nm1), function(x) (1:nrow(a) %in% c(sapply(x, grep, a$Contents, fixed=TRUE)))+0)`

Comment: `sapply(c(string1, string2), grep, x = a$Contents, value = TRUE)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need a function, may be you can try:

```
fun1 <- function(namePrefix, dat){ #assuming that the datasets have a common prefix i.e. `string`
pat <- paste0("^", namePrefix, "\\d")
nm1 <- ls(pattern=pat, envir=.GlobalEnv)
lst <- mget(nm1, envir=.GlobalEnv)
lst2 <- lapply(lst, function(x) 
      (1:nrow(dat) %in% c(sapply(x, grep, dat$Contents, fixed=TRUE)))+0) #your code
dat[names(lst2)] <- lst2
dat
```

}

```
 fun1("string", a)
 #            Contents other string1 string2
 #1     a house a home   111       1       0
 #2 cabin in the woods   121       1       0
```

Comment: can you comment on how this is working? I get lost at the envir=

Comment: @user3813578.  Here I assume that your vector object names all starts with prefix `string` followed by some `digits`. So I used the line `pat <- paste0("..`, which basically is pasting the input `string` followed by any digits `\\d`.  In the next line `nm1 <- `, it is asking for to look for objects with the specified pattern that are defined.  The `envir` argument is to look for objects in the `global environment`.  Then I use `mget` to return the value of those objects and it returns a list.  I used `lapply` as `lst` is a `list` and then applied your function and append the list to dat.